# HTML/CSS/Javascript/Center

Tags: javascript, html, css

have the following;
I'm displaying a 5000x5000 px image.
(it is a floor plan)
You can scroll over the image using the horizontal and vertical scroll bars
and the mouse pressed wheel.
at various points I have light points, if you press the button a popup will appear, letting you turn on or of the light or even dim.
to give you guys an idea.

Oke now I want this popup to be centered in the middle of the screen, NOT to the center of the image. Because if the view is top left, the popup would not be visible. visa versa with the lower right.
As the code is generated by an design studio I do not have many options.

An answer would be nice.

regards,

Ger

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The following will center a .popup div on the page, regardless of where you scroll or what parents the popup has.

```
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(50vh - (**INPUT POPUP HEIGHT**/2);
  left: calc(50vw - (**INPUT POPUP WIDTH**/2);
}
```

In case you don't know the exact height or width, there's a less clean version involving setting the popup margin to auto and it's parent to display: flex. Look at flexbox if you're having trouble with this.